# How to change mouse cursor in Android emulator

Tags: android, windows, android-emulator

I want to record a video (some sort of promo video) from Android emulator on my PC (Windows 7). Is there any way how to change default black mouse cursor with white borders to some custom look? There is an option in Windows but it only handles some applications but not 3rd party application with their custom cursor.
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Did you tried with the windows third party windows mouse pointer applications.. ? and screen recorder applications ?

Comment: hi .please have a look at this video. this also captured using third party video recorder in windows machine. around the mouse pointer you will be getting some yellow color marker or paint something to show what you are clicking.              http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mGwG8-chUEM

Comment: I didn't find any third party app that works. I also watched the video and that could be solution. But the author/uploader didn't respond.